# How to save dynamic add controls Data into database in MVC 4..?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

My Question is how to save all input into database.Because i dont know anything about it can any one help me to solve this problem 
    How to get all Data and how to pass data from view  to controller
can any one explain how  to dynamic text box value pass to controller

```
    Here is my Design:
            <div class="container" style="background-color:lightblue">
                <h2>Family Details</h2>
                <table class="table" id="maintable" style="border:solid">
                    <thead style="border-color:blue">
                        <tr>
                            <th>Name</th>
                            <th>Date Of Birth</th>
                            <th>Relation</th>
                            <th>Occupation</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr class="data-contact-person">
                            <td>

                                <input type="text" name="fname" class="form-control f-name01" /></td>
                            <td>
                                <input type="text" name="fdob" class="form-control l-name01" /></td>
                            <td>
                                <input type="text" name="frelation" class="form-control email01" /></td>               
                            <td>

                                 @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.occupation_id, Model.OccupationSelectList, "-----Select-----", new { })

                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <button type="button" id="btnAdd" class="btn btn-xs btn-primary classAdd">Add More</button>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                <button type="button" id="btnSubmit" class="btn btn-primary btn-md pull-right btn-sm">Submit</button>
            </div>

        Here Is MY Script:
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $(document).on("click", ".classAdd", function () { 
                    var rowCount = $('.data-contact-person').length + 1;
                    var cc = $("#occupation_id").html();
                    var contactdiv = '<tr class="data-contact-person">' +
                        '<td><input type="text" name="fname' + rowCount + '" class="form-control f-name01" /></td>' +
                        '<td><input type="text" name="fdob' + rowCount + '" class="form-control l-name01" /></td>' +
                        '<td><input type="text" name="frelation' + rowCount + '" class="form-control email01" /></td>' +
                         '<td><select name="occupation_id" id="occupation_id ' + rowCount + '">' + cc + '</select></td>' +
                        //'<td><button type="button" id="btnAdd" class="btn btn-xs btn-primary classAdd">Add More</button>' +
                        '<td><button type="button" id="btnDelete" class="deleteContact btn btn btn-danger btn-xs">Remove</button></td>' +

                        '</tr>';
                    $('#maintable').append(contactdiv); 
                });
            });
        </script>  
        <script>
            $(document).on("click", ".deleteContact", function () {
                $(this).closest("tr").remove();
            });
        </script>
```

Comment: Put css class for each dynamic textbox.eg: <input type="text" name="fname' + rowCount + '" class="form-control f-name01 fname" /></td>

Comment: then use the code like $(".fname").each(function () {
 $(this).val();// you get the each fname
});

Comment: that is not important i wanted to now if in inter four rows of  input then how data is goes to controller

Comment: but we dont know how much textbox user add so how can i find value of each textbox ...?

Comment: by this code  $(".fname").each(function () { $(this).val();// you get the each fname });  you will get all textbox and thier value.

Comment: use javascript object for data goes to controller .

Comment: ok i will check